# The strange encoding

Tags: cipher, language

***Good luck trying to solve this riddle.***



 010100100111100000100000011110000110111001111010001000000110110001110010011001110111001001100111111000101000000010011001011100100111100011100010100000001001100101110010011001100111001000101100001000000101011001111000011000010010000001101001011000100111000001110101001001110010000001110010011010010111100101110010011001010010111000100000010011100111101001110110001000000111000101101000011001110111001000100000011101010110001001100101011011000010110000100000011011100111100101110110001000000110000101110010001000000110011001101110011101100110011101100011011011100111011001100001011110100110110001101110011001010110010100101110001000000101011101100010001000000110111001110001011010000110000101101110011011000010000001000110011101010110100001110110001011000010000001010001011011100110000100100000010101100110000101100001011000100010000001100101011101100110111101101110001011100010000001010000011000100010000001110010011001010010000001110110011110000011111100100000



***I will post hints if they are needed***

Comment: Language tag? Is that useful in any sense?

Comment: Yes. That is sort of a hint to as what you shall have to do

Comment: Is this morse code?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton No it is not morse code. AHKieran has the first part correct

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This looks like

> an old riddle with each word translated into some random language and the whole thing run through a text->binary encoder.

The decoded text is something like

> Rx xnz lrgrg’rx’rfr, Vxa ibpu' riyre. Nzv qhgr ubel, nyv ar fnvgcnvazlnee. Wb nqhanl Fuhv, Qna Vaab evon. Pb re vx?
>
>  (after ROT13) Ek kam yetet’ek’ese, Ikn voch' evler. Ami dute hory, ali ne saitpainmyarr. Jo adunay Shui, Dan Inno riba. Co er ik?
>
>  (translated) I have cities, but no houses. I have mountains, but no trees. I have water, but no fish. What am I?

Apparently, the answer is

> [a map](https://doyouremember.com/64233/cities-no-houses).

NudgeNudge's answer has all the languages that were used :)

Comment: Well done. You got the correct answer

Comment: Well done. I am curisous about what the langages are here? I don't recognized most of them... and I know a few ones!

Comment: @Marvin Typed out those that I could find out :)

Comment: Hey! We posted a list of languages at pretty much the same time, feel free to complete your list with mine :)

Comment: @NudgeNudge Cool! I'll just point to your list since there were quite a few missing from mine.

Answer (score 8):

Adding to what everybody else said:

> Ek = I (Afrikaans)
> kam = have (Albanian)
> yetet'ek'ese = ???
> Ikn = but (Arabic)
> voch' = no (Armenian)
> evlər = houses (Azerbaijani)
> Āmi = I (Bengali)
> Dute = have (Basque)
> hory (горы) = mountains (Belarusian)
> ali = but (Bosnian)
> ne = no (Bulgarian)
> saitpainmyarr (သစ်ပင်မျာ) = trees (Burmese)
> Jo = I (Catalan)
> adunay = have (Cebuano)
> Shui (水) = water (Chinese)
> dan (但) = but (Chinese)
> inno = no (Corsican)
> riba = fish (Croatian)
> Co = What (Czech)
> Er = am (Danish)
> ik = I (Dutch)
> So just Google Translate languages in alphabetical order (not sure about the language of the list of languages, since if it was English "yetet'ek'ese' should be Amharic, as well as Basque being before Bengali.)

Answer (score 4):

Partial:

> Putting it through a binary to text translator gets:
>  **Rx xnz lrgrg’rx’rfr, Vxa ibpu' riyre. Nzv qhgr ubel, nyv ar fnvgcnvazlnee. Wb nqhanl Fuhv, Qna Vaab evon. Pb re vx?**
>  <s>I think it might not be this due to the double apostrophes</s>
>  Maybe some language uses double apostrophes, but OP confirms this step is correct.
>
>   rot13 of this text gives: (thanks @Marvin for the rot13 idea)
>  **Ek kam yetet’ek’ese, Ikn voch' evler. Ami dute hory, ali ne saitpainmyarr. Jo adunay Shui, Dan Inno riba. Co er ik?**
>  I believe each clause is a different language

Comment: the last part sounds dutch....

Answer (score 3):

Some additional informations

> the rot13 of AHKieran traduction gives something that looks like a language... and actually, it sounds like serveral ones. The first part looks Turkish: it translates to *"If the additional cam is enough"*.... 
>  Does not make sense for the moment.

Comment: You are correct to assume that there are different languages. However, there is no turkish in there.